# Redirecting questions related to basic definition/misunderstanding of entropy and black holes

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates

Every 2-3 days a question pops up on the site related to basic definition/misunderstanding of entropy/black holes. In the process of searching for related questions, I find that there are many answers covering many interesting and valid points. The number of such posts having quality content is so much that going through all of them takes a huge amount of time. I want some  suggestions for a suitable good answers to be redirected to for clearing these basic issues right away. Or does a master question for entropy as given in John Rennie's [Canonical question about the flow of time](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7431/) needs to be created?

Comment: Comments to the post (v2): To focus the discussion, consider to explicitly spell out the frequently and canonically asked questions in words, and perhaps include a couple of past examples.

Comment: I must get round to doing something about that *flow of time* question ...